# SQL query combine two columns that contain different data type

Tags: sql, types, qsqlquery

I need to retrive data from two columns one has char and the other is integer. I use the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(REQ.RQ_USER , _REQ_RQ_VC) AS 'MSR ID / Version'
from REQ
WHERE rq_type_id = '107'
```

I get syntax error. Is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: There probably is.  Step 1 is to edit the question and provide the database engine and error message.  Also format it properly so the code looks like code and not text.

Comment: Most likely the `CONCAT()` function in your database expects text, so you can try casting the number column to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to solve the issue by implementing the following syntax:

```
Select  '[' + CAST (REQ.RQ_USER_TEMPlATE_06 AS VARCHAR(5000)) + ']' + req.rq_req_id AS 'MSR ID / Version' FROM REQ WHERE rq_type_id = '107'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONVERT` function to convert integer to string. your final query should be as follows :

```
SELECT CONCAT( CONVERT(varchar(10), REQ.RQ_USER) , _REQ_RQ_VC) AS 'MSR ID / Version'
FROM REQ
WHERE rq_type_id = '107'
```

You can find more details about **CONVERT** function on the following link : [CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189534(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: What makes you so sure the database engine has a convert function?